# What is the origin of the culinary term "escabeche"

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the culinary term or dish "escabeche"

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escabeche) says "The origin of the word escabeche is Persian, and was brought to Spain by the Arabs during the Moorish conquests. The word derives from al-sikbaj[...]" This does not seem unlikely, is there any reason why you expect this information to be wrong or incomplete?

Comment: Coo. Three responses all quoting Wikipedia.

Comment: @AndrewLeach And why not?

Comment: @Kris No reason, except that presumably the asker could have looked there too.

Comment: I find this Q&A particularly interesting in light of the fact that the only "escabeche" I've ever known has been the [pickled carrots and onions](http://norecipes.com/pickled-jalapeno-escabeche-recipe) served as condiments in Mexican restaurants.  The "acid" or "vinegar" connection is there, but the dish is completely different from the original meaning of the word.

Answer (score 2):

[Escabeche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escabeche) is from Persian ***al-sikbaj***

> The origin of the word *escabeche* is Persian, and was brought to Spain by the Arabs during the Moorish conquests. The word derives from *al-sikbaj*, the name of a popular meat dish cooked in a sweet and sour sauce, usually vinegar and honey or date molasses.

The LA Times blog *[Forklore: The roots of escabeche](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/dailydish/2011/10/forklore-the-roots-of-escabeche.html)*:

> *Sikbaj* is a Persian word meaning "vinegar stew," and most medieval recipes describe it as lamb stewed with vinegar and spices.

This one makes for a good read.

And then, [Ichthyology](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/en_ichthyology/5184/escab%C3%A8che) thinks:

> The word is Spanish in origin or possible from the Farsi *sikbag* meaning acid food

Answer (score 0):

"*The origin of the word [escabeche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escabeche) is Persian, and was brought to Spain by the Arabs during the Moorish conquests. The word derives from al-sikbaj, the name of a popular meat dish cooked in a sweet and sour sauce, usually vinegar and honey or date molasses.*"